# ip address seen in ifconfig in os x which is not present in network setting

Tags: macos, ip-address, reboot, ifconfig

I have a macbook and some while back I must have assigned it an ip address of 192.168.2.1 on the ethernet interface. The problem is that the ip is still seen even when I have removed it from the network setting gui. When I see ifconfig, it is still seen. I have removed it from ifconfig through "ifconfig -alias" command but after reboot, it has come back again in ifconfig output. Is there any file in which this is stored permanently? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have Internet Sharing enabled (in System Preferences -> Sharing pane -> Internet Sharing)? Internet Sharing dynamically generates an IP address (or addresses) to use on the private network interface(s) (the ones enabled in the share "To computers using" list), and
192.168.2.1 is one of the common addresses it'll use.

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked. I was never able to troubleshoot it because I had once assigned this ip address myself also for connecting another laptop through ethernet cable.